# Playframework run concurrently without having to create entire untyped actor class for simple blocking operations (Java)

Tags: java, playframework, future

Hi there question on futures and execution contexts in Play framework (Java).

Right now here is how I currently run non blocking operations:

```
     public static Promise<Result> doOperation() {
         Promise<Result> r = Promise.wrap(
                 Patterns.ask(actorTest, "bla", 1000)).map(
                 new Function<Object, Result>() {
                     public Result apply(Object response) {
                         return ok(response.toString() + "\nOh look it returned");
                     }
                 });
         return r;
     }
```

But this seems to have too much extra code for simple operations such as just running a longer query.  Is there a way to do this without creating actors?  I read from [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/java/futures.html) that you can but am not sure how to integrate what is written with a play action.

Can someone give an example action say doOperation like above that can simply create a callable within the action that is run concurrently (not part of the play default context as this should never be blocked).

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaAsync).
An example:

```
public Promise<Result> doSomethingAsync(){
    return Promise.wrap(future(
            new Callable<Result>() {
                @Override 
                public Result call() throws JAXBException {
                    doWhateverIntensive();
                    return ok();
                } }, Akka.system().dispatcher()));
}
//Here is where the intensive task goes
public static doWhateverIntensive(){
    Thread.sleep(10*6000);
}
```